# MMS won't recieve pictures or video

Tags: lumia-635

I have a Nokia Lumia 635 phone with Windows 8 and T-Mobile is my provider. A month or so ago my phone stopped receiving photos and video. When I receive with it says "Get media content now" and when I tap it nothing happens. And when I send either it says it can't send message even though it can send texts. Please help.

Comment: Does restarting the phone resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your phone is probably missing the APN-Settings for MMS. Check this link for instructions on how to fix this for T-Mobile on Windows Phone 8:
https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-28065

> 1. From the start screen, swipe left.
> 2. Scroll down to and tap Settings.
> 3. Scroll down to and tap Network + wireless.
> 4. Scroll down to and tap cellular+SIM.
> 5. Scroll down to and tap SIM settings.
> 6. Tap add MMS APN.
> 7. Enter fast.t-mobile.com in the APN field.
> 8. Enter http://mms.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc in the MMSC (URL) field.
> 9. Leave all other fields unchanged.
> 10. Tap Save (disk icon).